# Front page as link in Views

Tags: views

This is pretty straight forward. How do I print a link to the homepage as field in Views?

I have added a global text field with html code `<a href="/">Home</a>` but this is just the path to the root & my website is installed in a subdomain.

Using D7 and latest [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module.

Comment: @NishantP I'm sure he meant `print l('front','',array('absolute'=>true));` - but I don't remember how to do it in views field easily.

Comment: @Mołot I think OP not being able to clear that how to explain there issue. First we need surety from OP.

Comment: Did you read the edited question?

Comment: Try to check the [LINK](https://www.drupal.org/node/1234862). I hope you are talking about this & you will get help from this url.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Unfortunately, that is not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a way to display a field as a link to frontpage in views (as mentioned in the question above, the "/" href does not take me to the frontpage, it is taking me to root domain).

Comment: @designarti if you installed Drupal into your sub-domain(something.maindomain.com), then the sub-domain root is your home page. You need the absolute url for any outside the sub-domain, something like `<a href="http://www.maindomain.com">Home</a>`

Comment: I had installed Drupal in a subdomain and the / href would've taken me to root domain. Maybe because I'm working on Xampp, localhost. The answer was given down the page. Thank you though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it should work this way:

- create the global text field, with the text as the link text -

[image]

- **then rewrite the results, and output as a link using `<front>` as the path -**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Didn't know it is that simple. And a very important asset - now I know <front> could be used as a token in Views.